# update pandas dataframe column not work on first time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe concated from some other dataframes, then I need to update some values in one column, and found that I have to do the same update twice. To find out what happened, I save the dataframe to disk and reload it, then do the update, now it works on the first time.

Is it a bug of pandas or I made some wrong?

I am using pandas 0.22.0 from conda 4.5.0

```
import pandas as pd
sum_trade = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv')
df = pd.concat(
    [
        sum_trade.loc[sum_trade.mon == 201806 ].groupby(['trade'])['cnt'].sum(),
        sum_trade.loc[sum_trade.mon == 201706 ].groupby(['trade'])['cnt'].sum(),
        sum_trade.loc[sum_trade.mon > 201800].groupby(['trade'])['cnt'].sum(),
        sum_trade.loc[sum_trade.mon < 201800].groupby(['trade'])['cnt'].sum()
    ],
    axis = 1
).reset_index()

df.columns = ['trade_code', 'cnt201806', 'cnt201706', 'cnt20181-6', 'cnt20171-6']

# subsititude ["1.blabla", "（1）foofoo", "其中：barbar"] to ["blabla", "foofoo", "barbar"]
pattern = re.compile(r'^（?\d?\.?\）?(其中：)?')

df.to_csv('temp.csv')

# The following line would not success 
df.trade_code = df.trade_code.map(lambda x: pattern.sub('', x.strip()))
display(df[df.trade_code.map(lambda x: '1' in x)])
# do same update again seems worked
df.trade_code = df.trade_code.map(lambda x: pattern.sub('', x.strip()))
display(df[df.trade_code.map(lambda x: '1' in x)])


# if load data from file, first update will sucesses
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
display(df[df.trade_code.map(lambda x: '1' in x)])
df.trade_code= df.trade_code.map(lambda x: pattern.sub('', x.strip()))
display(df[df.trade_code.map(lambda x: '1' in x)])
```

Here is some sample data of *somefile.csv*, which has about 2500 lines, and the concated df has about 200 lines (the names and numbers are faked):

```
    city        mon     trade                          cnt
0   达纳苏斯    201701  1.农业                         23458.0
1   达纳苏斯    201701  1.农副食品加工业             12345684.0
2   达纳苏斯    201701  1.房屋建筑业                      22109.0
3   达纳苏斯    201701  1.电信、广播电视和卫星传输服务       338.0
4   达纳苏斯    201701  1.电力、热力生产和供应业       133333.0
```

below are the 2 outputs of the above code, which shows that some substitutions were successful, while some were not. I ran the code several times, it was always the following 4 lines not updated at the first time. But if data or pattern has problem, the second update should not work too.

```
    trade   cnt201806   cnt201706   cnt20181-6  cnt20171-6
33  1.化学纤维制造业   0.0     123451.0    0.0     5432185.0
34  1.印刷和记录媒介复制业    5678913.0   7890153.0   5555504.0   112233185.0
63  1.金属制品业     98765804.0  4321563.0   34567919.0  22222256.0
82  1.金属制品、机械和设备修理业     8765493.0   3214929.0   3322113331.0    556677155.0

====================================================================

    trade   cnt201806   cnt201706   cnt20181-6  cnt20171-6
```

Comment: share some of the data pls.

Comment: @hootnot I have added sample data and output. It seems always the 4 lines have problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the data and found some trades are :

```
11.化学纤维制造业
11.印刷和记录媒介复制业
...
```

After the first substitution, they becomes:

```
1.化学纤维制造业
1.印刷和记录媒介复制业
...
```

That's why I have to substitute 2 times. I changed my pattern from `'^（?\d?\.?\）?(其中：)?'` to `'^（?\d*\.?\）?(其中：)?'` and all ok.

Thanks to all replies and comments.